# Rails, Is it possible to pass param from controller to a model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, model, refactoring

In my models I have several similar named methods to enable/disable certain features, like:

```
  def invisible
    self.update_attribute(:invisble, false)
  end

  def visible
    self.update_attribute(:invisble, true)
  end
```

Would it be possible to refactor this to a single method and pass an argument from controller? Or is there a better way to handle these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def set_visibility(param)
  self.update_attribute(:invisible, param == "true")
end
```

In controller:

```
@object.set_visibility(params[:visible])
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: just like that, moved the the param == default inside the def line

Comment: One thought regarding naming conventions. One could have a is_visible method to check that returns true or false ( or better use just visible?). Shoulden't def visibility be renamed to def set_visibility? Not sure about the naming conventions but thanks for the answer, will accept in 10min

Comment: I've updated the method name, not sure if it's better to create another method `visible?` or not.